# Cannot access the server via ssh after apt-get update

Tags: linux, ssh

I have did `apt-get update` in my server - Linux Debian and after that I rebooted the server but now can't access it via ssh.

When I open `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` it showed everything prefix with `#`. I typed `ps ax | grep sshd` it shows `6646 ? ss 0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd`

Can you help please?

Comment: `apt-get update` alone would not do that. Did you perhaps run `apt-get upgrade` either instead or also?

Comment: What's the output of `sudo lsof -i | grep ssh` ?

Comment: Actually now I found that the server is not connected to the internet,, but it is physically connected and can ping the router ip address but it is not pinging outside. I did yesterday like this apt-get update && apt-get install php5-curl . I changed the ethernet cable but still the same.

Comment: If you can ping the Router, there is no need to change wires. Can you ping ips in the Internet?

Comment: I can ping yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As root check to see if IPTables is in place.

```
# iptables -L
```

Check the output to make sure there isn't a restriction there.  In the event that there are some rules there post them back here so that we can see which one could be holding you up.